# Isotope Element - Click to Enlarge Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am attempting to setup an Isotope (version 2) Page.

On this page there are elements a person can click which then enlarges the box and the gallery redraws itself.

The problem is on the first click the gallery doesn't appear to be triggering the layout to redraw itself.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$container.on( 'click', '.element', function() {
  // change size of item by toggling large class
  $( this ).toggleClass('large');
  $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfape/4/) with a working example of the problem.

[Here is what I am attempting to achieve](http://cdpn.io/qzhIb).

How do I solve my problem and make the gallery work as intended?

Comment: was half year ago I used isotope, I remember I set some setting where the grid uses 1px... That solved a lot of problems. Instead of setting the grid to like 100px and so on... Hope it helps :) ... setting column width to 1 px... anyways, you shoudl send the iframe link http://s.codepen.io/desandro/fullpage/qzhIb? so you can see the source code :P

Comment: @Medda86 - I am not sure I follow you. Also the code for the pen can be found by clicking edit pen (bottom left) or by [clicking this link](http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/qzhIb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out this code in my CSS was causing the problem:

```
.isotope, .element {
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -moz-transition: all .4s;
  -o-transition: all .4s;
  transition: all .4s;
}
```

Removing that fixed my problem. I would assume the transition speed was throwing off the layout.